# Sending mail with Go and Postfix in localhost

Tags: go, postfix-mta

I have the following code in my Go app.

```
func sendMail(addr, from, subject, body string, to []string) error {
    r := strings.NewReplacer("\r\n", "", "\r", "", "\n", "", "%0a", "", "%0d", "")

    c, err := smtp.Dial(addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer c.Close()
    if err = c.Mail(r.Replace(from)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for i := range to {
        to[i] = r.Replace(to[i])
        if err = c.Rcpt(to[i]); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    w, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    msg := "To: " + strings.Join(to, ",") + "\r\n" +
        "From: " + from + "\r\n" +
        "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n" +
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" +
        "\r\n" + base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(body))

    _, err = w.Write([]byte(msg))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return c.Quit()
}
```

Which I found here on SO.
Then I have this call in my code :

```
if err := sendMail("127.0.0.1:25", "SENDER", "Subject", body, []string{sendNewPassword.Email}); err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
```

The thing is, I am not getting any error on my logs but the mail is never arriving. And when I see the mail log at **sudo cat /var/log/mail.log** there is nothing relevant there. Not even warnings.

Another thing worth to point out is that I can send a mail using the standard tools just fine. For instance : **cat "Some text" | mailx -s 'Test mail' myemail@gmail.com**
Works perfectly fine. This is my **main.cf** for postfix :

```
[~]@Ubuntu1910 #> cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = Ubuntu1910
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, Ubuntu1910, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only 
inet_protocols = all
```

Can someone see something wrong with my config? (or my code)

Edit : This also fails by the way :

```
curl --url 'smtps://localhost:25' --ssl-reqd --mail-from 'username@gmail.com' --mail-rcpt 'myemail@gmail.com' --upload-file mail.txt --insecure

curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Comment: A couple of assorted points. 1) Please first make it sure as a minimal command-line app, without any HTTP in it: the less moving parts a program has, the easier it is to debug it; 2) Why won't you try using the "all-in-one" [`smtp.SendMail`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#SendMail) function which appears to "do the right thing" w.r.t. speaking the SMTP protocol instead of attempting to hand-craft a full session, ostensibly not really understanding how the protocol works? …

Comment: …3) The latter error is irrelevant to the problem at hand and is because SMTP**S** which you appear to be using implies that the service speaks SSL/TLS on its port directly, but that's not the case with neither of the standard ports for accepting mails—25 (MTA) and 587 (message submission). Instead, there is a nearly universal extension to SMTP, called, STARTTLS, which may be used by a client to "upgrade" an insecure session to use SSL/TLS and then restart the normal exchange using the secure tunnel. From the docs, it appears that your `curl` encantation should be using the `smtp://` scheme…

Comment: …and the `--ssl` command-line option.

Comment: @kostix You are right in the curl command. smtp instead of smtps works fine. But not form my code. The reason why I used this hand crafted version is because from the place I got it, it was stated the package from GO's standard library wont work when hitting localhost. But ill try what you say and update here with the outcome. Thanks for replying

Comment: From here I got my implementation : https://gadelkareem.com/2018/05/03/golang-send-mail-without-authentication-using-localhost-sendmail-or-postfix/ @kostix

Comment: @kostix If I am using the standard library which auth should I use?

Comment: [The code](https://golang.org/src/net/smtp/smtp.go#L319) does not attempt to perform auhentication if the `a` argument to `smtp.SendMail` is `nil`. Have you tried using that fact? I'm not sure why you're beleiving that some random post on the 'net is actually correct when the code of the Go stdlib is right here at your fingertips. 

Comment: @kostix I have the weird custom of trusting people then! :D Ill try as you say thanks so much for clearing all of this

Comment: same code, works fine for me